# Twig : url_decode

Tags: php, symfony, twig, twig-extension

I encoded an url parameter with the twig filter url_encode.

```
// app.request.query.get("date") output 01/04/2016

href="{{ path('page', {date: app.request.query.get("date")|url_encode}) }}">
```

which output in the url

```
date=01%252F04%252F2016
```

So in the requested page with url parameters

```
 {{ app.request.query.get("date") }}
```

display 01%2F04%2F2016 but i'd like to have 01/04/2016

I tried using raw filter and also did a twig extension :

```
<?php
namespace SE\AppBundle\Twig;

class htmlEntityDecodeExtension extends \Twig_Extension
{
    public function getFilters()
    {
        return array(
            new \Twig_SimpleFilter('html_entity_decode', array($this, 'htmlEntityDecode'))
        );
    }

    public function htmlEntityDecode($html)
    {
        $html = html_entity_decode($html);
        return $html;
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'html_entity_decode_extension';
    }
}
```

But even with this it keeps displaying 01%2F04%2F2016

I get the same result in my controller method with :

```
echo html_entity_decode($request->query->get('date'));
```

What is the proper way to do this?

UPDATE :

the date is from an input of type 'text'. No this is a simple string with numbers and / .

Comment: try writing a filter that do an url_decode and apply it twice if is needed

Comment: Does html_entity_decode is not suppose to decode 01%2F04%2F2016 to 01/04/2016? I tried to apply it many times but same result.

Comment: Ah my bad, i should use php function urldecode(). Well if it is what you mean by url_decode. I'll let you set the answer.

Comment: How can you apply  `urldecode` in Twig?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no need to url-encode the parameter of the query string in the first place, as it's already done by the function that generate the path.

`01%252F04%252F2016` is doubly urlencoded. PHP, when gets the request, already decode that value to `01%2F04%2F2016`, but since you encoded it twice, it's still urlencoded. You need to use `urldecode` function to decode it. Or even better: *don't urlencode it twice.*

It's fine:

```
{{ path('page', {date: app.request.query.get("date")}) }}
```

**UPDATE**

Found [this](https://github.com/symfony/routing/blob/master/Generator/UrlGenerator.php#L270) in the source code:

```
// "/" and "?" can be left decoded for better user experience, see
// http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#section-3.4
$url .= '?'.(false === strpos($query, '%2F') ? $query : strtr($query, array('%2F' => '/')));
```

So, the `/` is left deliberately url-decoded.

Comment: That is the weird thing, this output date=01/04/2016

Comment: where did you see that output? check from the html source of the page

Comment: But urldecode() seems to do the job instead of html_entity_decode.

Comment: This output is from url not from html. This is why i encoded it at the first place.

Comment: So, check the html, and check if the generated path is url-encoded correctly: something like `/page/?data=01%2F04%2F2016`. Then your job is done. If your browser shows you an already url-decoded uri, it's just a deception of the browser.

Comment: The html is still ?from_date=01/04/2016 (By the way the date parameter is a string).

Comment: what's your symfony version? there's something that you didn't show us?

Comment: 2.7, i will switch to 3 really soon. I think i showed everything. I'll update the post with the fact i'm using an input of type text, so not a standard date format.

Comment: just tried by myself, with surprise I get your same result - give me a minute to check why